# Validate integrity of an Oracle column

Tags: sql, oracle, checksum

A colleague has extracted a column from an Oracle database and written the column to file locally. I would like to validate the integrity of the data in the column.

Calculating a checksum both server-side on the table's column and locally on the column in the file seems like a good option. Nevertheless, we are using an old version of Oracle and the `CHECKSUM` function is not available. (I believe it was introduced in 21c.) I have tried the `STANDARD_HASH` function, but it hashes each value in the column rather than the *entire* column.

Given the constraints of no native `CHECKSUM` function available, what would be the best approach to validating the data in the column? Hand roll my own checksum function? Somehow combine all hashed values into some sort of single metahash?

---

### Edit

As an example, say I'm talking about the [*mtcars*](https://gist.github.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b) dataset and it's the `MODEL` column.

```sql
SELECT MODEL FROM TEST.MTCARS
```

```
                 MODEL
1            Mazda RX4
2        Mazda RX4 Wag
3           Datsun 710
4       Hornet 4 Drive
5    Hornet Sportabout
6              Valiant
7           Duster 360
8            Merc 240D
9             Merc 230
10            Merc 280
11           Merc 280C
12          Merc 450SE
13          Merc 450SL
14         Merc 450SLC
15  Cadillac Fleetwood
16 Lincoln Continental
17   Chrysler Imperial
18            Fiat 128
19         Honda Civic
20      Toyota Corolla
21       Toyota Corona
22    Dodge Challenger
23         AMC Javelin
24          Camaro Z28
25    Pontiac Firebird
26           Fiat X1-9
27       Porsche 914-2
28        Lotus Europa
29      Ford Pantera L
30        Ferrari Dino
31       Maserati Bora
32          Volvo 142E
```

What I'd like is a *single value*, like a checksum, that I can use to validate the integrity of the entire column in my local file.

If I hash this, I get a hash for each value in the `MODEL` column, like so:

```sql
SELECT STANDARD_HASH(MODEL, 'MD5') AS MYHASH
FROM TEST.MTCARS
```

```
                                                           MYHASH
1  f4, 37, 48, 21, e3, f2, bc, 56, b5, e7, 70, 02, 61, 40, 79, 86
2  57, 77, 13, 48, d3, 40, 59, 3b, 36, 6e, ac, c1, 79, a3, e2, 54
3  60, 1b, 77, cc, 68, af, eb, b2, a1, 7b, e2, 8d, ed, 08, c4, 61
4  8b, 69, 01, 91, 0c, fa, f2, 5a, 19, 6f, 06, ae, bc, cd, ff, b3
5  24, d4, 1b, df, ab, 0e, 2a, c4, 0c, fa, 72, a3, 2c, 0f, 7f, 1b
6  13, d1, e6, 75, 17, 0a, 97, 5d, e6, 8c, 9e, b4, f3, 81, da, f4
7  c7, 4d, ac, 8e, ed, ca, cc, b0, 86, af, 9c, b1, fd, 9e, e6, ef
8  8e, b1, ab, 3a, 72, 86, 5e, cf, f4, 53, f8, 8b, 40, 97, 79, 73
9  e7, 07, 43, 26, df, 9d, 4f, 84, 49, ee, a5, 15, 80, 6f, b3, 93
10 64, 53, 4b, 23, 60, 3a, f8, c8, 5e, d3, f0, 1d, 05, 83, 17, ff
11 be, b9, f0, 58, 68, a2, ed, 9c, 6f, de, c8, 23, ff, 4a, a0, 48
12 08, ff, f1, 58, 92, f8, 57, 0b, 57, 5d, 8e, bb, 2a, 0c, 8f, 88
13 d6, 39, 29, e2, 9f, 1a, 61, 5d, 7d, a8, 49, d5, 24, b9, 62, e6
14 d1, 25, 1c, 8b, 12, cb, c8, de, c5, 3d, e3, bf, b4, 86, ef, ca
15 a0, 98, 51, cb, 6c, c2, 67, 3e, 2f, 06, 59, fc, 9c, 23, 96, b3
16 05, ad, 97, c4, ca, 7e, 4d, 2d, 87, 02, 7e, 33, 58, 1f, 74, aa
17 88, 98, 4b, 0c, d9, 66, 4a, bb, 63, 77, cf, 20, fd, 18, 4c, 66
18 34, 2b, a0, 55, 74, fb, 83, 5e, b3, 5d, b2, b4, 93, 63, ed, 15
19 81, 7a, 10, a8, 5e, 3d, 3f, 42, fd, b9, ce, 5b, 43, 40, 72, b3
20 d8, 6d, 32, eb, 99, df, 82, da, 2b, 87, 2b, 9f, 6e, 0d, 72, 53
21 dd, 24, 9f, 01, 8d, df, 61, d1, 26, 06, e8, d4, d1, 44, 87, 43
22 f9, 4f, 2b, 84, 82, fb, 0b, 4b, 22, 97, f9, f3, 52, 96, 45, 44
23 56, 20, 59, 4c, 17, 03, 11, 7a, a2, 2e, 67, 00, 29, 70, 1b, ef
24 0d, ac, 29, e0, 05, d7, 48, cb, 22, 54, c3, cf, b8, 91, 78, 9c
25 ac, 2e, 37, 8a, ee, 95, 0a, 33, 0b, 49, 8d, 2d, a4, 3c, d7, 0c
26 45, f0, 50, f0, f7, 74, bc, 08, f3, fa, c2, 01, 68, d0, 70, 1b
27 55, 7a, 8f, 9a, 72, b4, 60, 1c, 5c, 72, 3c, e6, 9a, 01, bf, 8f
28 83, 8b, 1e, 9b, 57, 21, 81, 2f, a1, 76, f3, d8, e5, da, 4e, d1
29 43, 59, 33, 4f, 92, 5c, ea, 65, fb, 03, 34, 6c, 2f, 31, e7, 34
30 4e, f2, c6, c6, 42, 78, fb, 5b, c5, 71, d2, 50, cf, a1, ad, f9
31 ab, 59, 1c, 32, 78, 84, ea, b2, fa, 4a, b0, 77, b3, 16, b6, 14
32 42, ce, b9, 55, 14, 0f, f5, 7e, 8a, c2, cc, ef, 8d, 64, 4c, 7e
```

This hasn't further my solution at all because I'd have to download as much data as if I simply downloaded the column itself for comparison against the file version.

Comment: What do you mean, " hashes each value in the column rather than the entire column."?  Please show the data and expected behavior and what version of oracle? Why do you think the file data may be incorrect?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with a toy example. And there's no reason to think the data is incorrect - but I need to be able to verify that.

Comment: How much data (characters, bytes) are you working with?

Comment: you mean you want a hash of the column from all the rows?

Comment: @APC That's a good question. I don't have a good answer, but it's around 400M rows of free text that could each be the length of an address.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, that was my thought. The idea was that I could use the hash to compare server-side columns and local file columns with just a single value. I don't know if that makes sense, though, or if there's a more sensible option.

Comment: Back to my main question, why do you think you need to do this?  Saving results to a file is not normally a data corrupting issue.  Or it is a security issue, someone changed the file contents?  Trying to understand what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It's really an assurance that when we transfer entire databases from our servers to, say, a parquet file on someone's laptop that the data has not been corrupted. I agree that the data is probably fine, but this will be done with large datasets often, so eventually something will go wonky and we want to identify issues early.

Comment: One option is to `BIT_XOR()` all the hashes of a column, to produce the "meta-hash" you described. A simple procedure using a cursor can do the trick.

Comment: However, there's a significant issue with `STANDARD_HASH`. It works over bytes, not characters. If the column is VARCHAR2 (is it an address?) then there's an encoding present. Your external file should mimic the same encoding for a SHA1 method to return the same hash. For example, if your file uses UTF-8 and oracle is using ASCII, then the hashes won't match. I would suggest you find about the encoding to make sure you'll get consistent results.